# In 'Visual Studio 2015 Test Explorer', getting Message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2015, karma-jasmine

I am using Karma, Jasmine in Visual Studio 2015 update 2 to run unit test for my application.

I have used the 'Karma Test Adapter' to do so.

My Karma.conf.js is:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      { pattern: 'src/test/app.component.spec.js', included: true },
      { pattern: 'src/**/*spec.ts', included: false },
      { pattern: 'src/**/**/*spec.ts', included: false },
      { pattern: 'src/**/**/**/*spec.ts', included: false },
       { pattern: 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js', included: true, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js', included: true, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js', included: true, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js', included: true, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js', included: true, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'src/**/*.spec.ts', included: true },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js', included: true },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js', included:true }
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
})
}
```

My test file is:

```
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
describe('Test Search in InSite', () => {
var cc = new AppComponent();
it('Data Enquiry should return something', 
() => {expect(cc.search()).toBe("Helloo"); });
});
```

My Package.json is:

> `{
>     "name": "angular2-webpack",
>     "version": "1.0.0",
>     "description": "Angular 2",
>     "main": "index.js",
>     "scripts": {
>       "dev": "webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback --content-base ./src --open",
>       "postinstall": "rm -rf typings && typings install && npm run webdriver-update",
>       "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
>       "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
>       "typings": "typings"
>     },
>     "author": "",
>     "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE",
>     "dependencies": {
>       "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
>       "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
>       "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
>       "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
>       "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
>       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
>       "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.6",
>       "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
>       "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
>       "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
>       "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
>       "require": "^2.4.20",
>       "requirejs": "^2.2.0"
>     },
>     "devDependencies": {
>       "babel-core": "^6.3.17",
>       "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
>       "codelyzer": "^0.0.23",
>       "copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
>       "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
>       "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
>       "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
>       "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
>       "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
>       "karma": "^0.13.15",
>       "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.0",
>       "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.0",
>       "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
>       "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.1",
>       "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.6",
>       "karma-vs-reporter": "^0.8.0",
>       "protractor": "^3.0.0",
>       "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
>       "stylus": "^0.54.2",
>       "stylus-loader": "^2.0.0",
>       "ts-loader": "^0.8.0",
>       "tslint": "^3.10.2",
>       "tslint-loader": "^2.1.4",
>       "typescript": "^1.7.3",
>       "typings": "^1.0.0",
>       "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.13",
>       "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.0"
>     }
>   }`
>   
>   I am getting an error 'Message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import' in Test Explorer. Kindly let me the solution.

Thanks in Advance
-Saggy